# Dúvida de Atribuição de valores em c

Tags: c, operadores

Eis o meu código , por que se tem alteração nas outras variáveis , eu não estou apenas mudando a acada linha a variável valor? qual motivo de as outras se alterarem?

```
int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, valor = 0;

valor = a;
printf("%d\n" , valor);

valor = b++;
printf("%d\n", valor);

valor = ++c;
printf("%d\n", valor);

valor += b;
printf("%d\n", valor);

valor *= c;
printf("%d\n", valor);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao fazer b++ ou ++b estás a mexer na variavel b

É diferente que fazer valor+=b, neste caso so mexe na variavel "valor"

Comment: então a instrução por exemplo: valor=++b , está somando +1 na variável b além de alterar a b , é isso?

Comment: @VitorGonçalves sim, isso é operador de incremento, entao vai somar primeiro à variavel b

Comment: resumindo: incremento e decremento alteram as variáveis , já atribuição não?

Comment: @VitorGonçalves exatamente, ao fazer

valor = b++; //aqui o "b" teria o valor de 2
valor = b; // aqui o "b" teria o valor de 3

valor ia ter o valor de 3, porque ao fazer b++ so incrementa a seguir

Comment: é meio confuso , ainda mais quando o ++ fica na frente da variável kk , ela 'calcula' mas não 'aplica' igual o ++ atrás , é complicado mas uma hora vai , obrigado!! :)

Comment: x++ calcula mas nao aplica logo;  ++x calcula e aplica. Pensa dessa forma para facilitar

Answer (score 4):

- **Caso 1:**

  `valor = a;` atribui `a` à variável `valor`;
- **Caso 2:**

  `valor = b++;` é o mesmo que a seguinte sequência:

  `valor = b;`

  `b = b + 1;`
- **Caso 3:**

  `valor = ++c;` é o mesmo que a seguinte sequência:

  `c = c + 1;`

  `valor = c;`
- **Caso 4:**

  `valor += b;` é o mesmo que a seguinte sequência:

  `valor = valor + b;`
- **Caso 5:**

  `valor *= c;` é o mesmo que a seguinte sequência:

  `valor = valor * c;`